# socket io angular, multiple messages received on unique event

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io, chat

I am working on a real time chat app using socket.io and angular.
When a user log in a first connection is created, then when i clicks on his penfriend he joins a certain room, then he can send and receive messages, until there everything works fine.
I have this little problem, when i leave a room and enters another one, and send a message, this message is sent twice (not to the database, but it shows up twice in the chat container).
When i leaves this room again and enter another one to send another message, this new message will be sent three times, and so on.
At first i thought it might be a subscription issue, but even when i unsubscribe to all the events in my class it is still the same.
Could someon explain me please ?

Here my ts.component :

```
export class ChatDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('formMessage') input!: ElementRef;

  room!:Room;
  roomID!:string;
  currentUser!:User;
  penFriend!:User;
  penFriendID!:any;
  messages!:Message[] | undefined;
  formMessage!: string;
  msgObject!: Message;
  socketSub!:Subscription;
  currentUserSub!:Subscription;
  chatSub!: Subscription;
  penFriendSub!:Subscription;
  sendDBSub!:Subscription;


  constructor(
              private chatService: ChatService,
              private route:ActivatedRoute,
              private userService: UserService,
              private router:Router,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private socketService: SocketService
              ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initRoom()
    this.socketSub = this.socketService.getMessageObservable()
        .subscribe((data:Message) => {
          if(!data || !this.messages)return
          this.messages.push(data)
        })
  }

  initRoom(){
    this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params)=>{
      if(!params['id']) return;
      this.roomID = params['id']
      this.initUser()
    })

  }

  initUser(){
  this.currentUserSub = this.userService.getUserFromLocalStorage()
    .subscribe((user:any) => {
      this.currentUser = user.user;
      this.getRoom()
    })
  }

  getRoom(){
  this.chatSub = this.chatService.getSingleRoom(this.roomID)
    .subscribe((room:any)=>{
      this.room = room.room
      this.getPenFriend()
          })
    }

    getPenFriend(){
      this.penFriendID = this.room.users?.find((userID:any) => userID !== this.currentUser._id);
    this.penFriendSub = this.userService.getUserByID(this.penFriendID)
          .subscribe((data:any) => {
            this.penFriend = data.user;
            this.initMsg()
          })

    }

    initMsg(){
      this.messages = this.room.chat;
    }

    onSend(msg:string){
      if(!msg || !this.roomID || !this.currentUser._id)return ;
      this.msgObject = {content: msg, room: this.roomID, poster:this.currentUser._id};
      this.socketService.onSendMessage(this.msgObject);
      this.socketService.SendMessageToDB(this.msgObject)
          .subscribe();
          this.input.nativeElement.value = '';
    }


    onExit(){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/chats');
      this.socketService.onLeaveRoom(this.roomID);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.socketSub.unsubscribe();
      this.currentUserSub.unsubscribe();
      this.chatSub.unsubscribe();
      this.penFriendSub.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

And here is the socket Service :

```
export class SocketService {

  URL = environment.BASE_SERVER_URL
  API_MESSAGE = environment.MESSAGE_URL;
  API_ROOMS = environment.GET_SINGLE_ROOM_BY_ID;
  socket!: any;
  currentUserID!:string;
  message$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

  constructor( private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

  ioConnect(email:string,password:string){
    this.socket = io(this.URL);
    this.socket.emit('login', {email,password})
    this.socket.on('new_message', (data:Message) => {
    this.message$.next(data)
     }
    )
  }

  getCurrentUserID(){
    this.currentUserID = localStorage.getItem('userID') || '';
  }

  onSendMessage(msg:Message):void{
    this.socket.emit('send_message', msg);
  }

  onJoinRoom(room:string|undefined){
    if(!room) return;
    this.socket.emit('join_room', room)
  }

  onLeaveRoom(room:string){
    this.socket.emit('leave_room', room)
  }

  getMessageObservable(): Observable<Message> {
    return this.message$.asObservable()
  }

  SendMessageToDB(data:Message){
  return this.http.post<Message>(this.API_MESSAGE, data)
    .pipe(
        tap((data:any)=> {
          const { _id, room } = data.newMessage
          this.sendMessageToRoom(_id, room)
        }))
  }

  sendMessageToRoom(msgID:string, msgRoom:string){
  return this.http.patch<Message>(this.API_ROOMS + msgRoom,{
      "message": msgID
      })
      .subscribe()
  }

  socketOut(){
    this.socket.emit('end');
  }
}
```

Finally here is the socket file from the server side:

```
    const axios = require("axios");

const socketFunctions = (io, socket) => {
  console.log("new connection " + socket.id);
  socket.on("login", data => {
    const { email, password } = data;
    axios
      .post("http:/localhost:3001/api/v1/chatApp/auth/login", {
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then(res => {
        loadEvents(socket);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
};

loadEvents = socket => {
  socket.on("join_room", room => {
    socket.join(room);
    console.log("user joined the room" + room);
    socket.on("send_message", data => {
      socket.emit("new_message", {
        poster: data.poster,
        content: data.content,
        room,
        date: Date.now(),
      });
    });
  });

  socket.on("leave_room", room => {
    console.log("user left the room" + room);
  });

  socket.on("connect_error", err => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
  });

  socket.on("end", function () {
    socket.disconnect(0);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });
};
module.exports = socketFunctions;
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `onSend(msg:string)` gets called multiple times. Did you trace it as to why this might happen? Please share more relevant code - as currently nothing inclines that it's being called multiple times.

Comment: The function onSend() is called once.

Comment: It is the socketSubs in the ngOnInit() that is receiveing the data two times

Comment: I've added the socket from the server side in the main question if it can help

Comment: I think the problem happens in the room creation part, when the user enters a room for the first time, everything works correctly, but in subsequent times, you can't do whether this room already exists or not. that's why. The reason is that when creating a new room, the message is sent twice

Comment: Ok thank you Ali i managed to sort this out by taking the "send_message" event out of the "join_room" !!